# FAILURE : No target filename specified

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

```
path = '/mnt/Data/30_Stages_Encours/2023/ZonesHumides_Sarah/donnee_dezippee/sentinel2/2020/'
dir = os.listdir(path)
for i in dir : 
# i = SENTINEL2X_20200415-000000-000_L3A_T31UES_C_V2-1
        if i.split('.')[-1] != "zip" and i.split('/')[-1] != "traitee":
            print("IMAGE EN COURS:", i)
            for bande in bandes :
# bande = B3 or else
                nom_image = i + '_FRC_' + bande + '.tif' 
                nom_image_r = i + '_FRC_' + bande + '_r.tif' # nom image superimpose 
                image_entree = os.path.join(path, i, nom_image) # path to one image
                image_sortie = os.path.join(path, i, nom_image_r) # path to an image that doesn't exist yet


                os.system('gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326'+image_entree+' '+image_sortie)
```

I would like to be able to no rename my output of gdal warp or be able to rename it with a variable.
I just want to add '_r' at the end of my input image but with this method I get the error

```
FAILURE : No target filename specified
```

EDIT :
with an example more clear, this gives me the same error :

```
 import os 
image_entree = 'path/to/image.tif'
image_sortie = 'path/to/image_r.tif'
os.system('gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326'+image_entree+' '+image_sortie +'r')
```

Comment: At least the closing single quote is missing in `'+image_sortie`

Comment: with os.system that's how input variables works - at least with os.system('otbcli_ExtractROI..) - tried different version and doesn't work otherwise

Comment: thanks, @user30184 trying to explain in my head how os.system works helped me spot the error - you need to tell os that there is a gap between the two variables with a string space as such : os.system('gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 '+image_entree+' '+image_sortie)

Comment: Right, I was looking too fast. The true problem was that "image_entree" was added after EPSG:4326 without a space.

Answer (score 2):

thanks, @user30184 trying to explain in my head how `os.system` works helped me spot the error - you need to tell `os` that there is a gap between the two variables with a string space as such :

```py
os.system('gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 '+image_entree+' '+image_sortie)
```

With f-string notation:

```
os.system(f"gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 {image_entree} {image_sortie}")
```

Comment: Using f-string notation also improves readability. e.g. `os.system(f"gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 {image_entree} {image_sortie}")`